# Prove the function is not differentiable at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Take the function 
$$
\begin{cases}f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)/\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) & \text{when } 0<\lvert (x,y)\rvert<\pi\\  
0 & \text{when } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

I got that this function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. I calculated the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ of which both were $0$ and trying to show the definition of differentiability is not satisfied but I keep getting that it is. Plz help.

Comment: The function is not *bounded* near (0,0), hence it cannot be continuous at (0,0), hence it cannot be differentiable at (0,0).

Comment: Are you sure? I read the condition $|(x,y)| < \pi$ to mean $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \pi$. Near the origin, writing $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $f$ as a function of $r$ is $r^2/\sin r$ which behaves nicely. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess one could interpret $\sin((x^2+y^2)^.5)$ as $\sin((x^2+y^2)^5)$...

Comment: I did something similar to Simon S

Comment: The partials don't exist at the origin.

Comment: Hmmm... Writing $\sin((x^2+y^2)^{.5})$ to denote $\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ while being as close as possible typographically to $\sin((x^2+y^2)^5)$? The modified version is definitely better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ you get a limit of the form:

$$\lim_{ h\rightarrow0}\displaystyle\frac{h}{\sin |h|}$$

which does not exist.